# Render problem in EEVEE

Tags: rendering

I have a problem with rendering.
Textures are spoiled or underlying textures are spoiling the top layer textures.
I have tried to play with settings but I could not find the reason.

It looks good in render mode if it is looked without camera, but when it is looked under camera texture looks spoiled or overlying each other.
[image]

Comment: Can you attach your .blend file? And also, you did not provide two images.

Comment: I could not upload second image. So how can I do it here?
The lines in the Trench disappear when it is looked without camera. these are the sides of the cubes and this distortion becomes even bigger when the camera much farther.

Comment: Try uploading your .blend file on this link and follow the instructions: https://blend-exchange.com/